# Timing chain cover gasket

Tags: toyota, coolant, leak, corolla, timing

I posted a few weeks ago about cooolant leaking from the timing chain cover of my 2002 Corolla:

[Corolla - Coolant leaking from timing chain cover](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/39959/4152)

I went ahead and started to do job: removing the timing chain cover and reseal it. The pictures attached are showing what the timing chain cover looks like, once removed. Specifically, there is a white color around the water pump. **Is it a sign that coolant was leaking from there like I was suspecting?** I am not an expert and would appreciate any insights from these pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there is supposed to be any coolant flowing within the timing chain cover. So, you definitely have something else as the problem that poor seals in the timing chain cover. Sounds like a water pump issue to me.